# How can I assign changing variable name to a changing variable name?

Tags: r, for-loop, assign

How can I assign changing variable name to a changing variable name?
I've seen similar questions but they are about assigning values to changing variable names.
I have a list of variables named like "house1", " house2", etc. Each has a value assigned to it. E.g. house1 = 1 dollar, house2 = 50 dollars, etc.
I want to create variables of type "building1", "building2", etc. and assign each "house" to a corresponding "building". So, I want to have in the end building1 = 1 dollar, building2 = 50 dollars, etc.

```
for(i in 1:15) 
{ 
  name_house <- paste("house", i, sep = "")
  name_building <- paste("building",i, sep="")
  assign(name_house, name_building)
}
```

I know someone would suggest creating a list of variables which contains all the buildings, but houses were already set as different variables before me, and I was asked to do building in the same way.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I'm given "houses" - variables with some values like house1=25 dollars, house2=40 dollars,etc. What I want to do is you could say, rename them (but keeping both houses and buildings, i.e. create a copy and rename the copy), so that I had "buildings" with the corresponding values. building1=25 dollars, building2 = 40dollars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you begin with this -

```
( x <- setNames(paste(1:4, "dollars"), paste0("house", 1:4)) )
#      house1      house2      house3      house4 
# "1 dollars" "2 dollars" "3 dollars" "4 dollars"
```

Then you can use the following to create an identical vector with different names

```
setNames(x, sub("house", "building", names(x), fixed = TRUE))
#   building1   building2   building3   building4 
# "1 dollars" "2 dollars" "3 dollars" "4 dollars"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have taken `houses` and its corresponding values in a `data.frame`. See, if this works for you,

```
houses <- c("house1", "house2", "house3",  "house4", "house5")
name_house <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
df <- data.frame(houses, name_house)
> df
#houses name_house
#1 house1          1
#2 house2          2
#3 house3          3
#4 house4          4
#5 house5          5
```

Then replacing the values of `house` with `buildings`

```
df$houses <- gsub("house", "building", df$houses)
> df
# houses name_house
#1 building1          1
#2 building2          2
#3 building3          3
#4 building4          4
#5 building5          5
```